# Построение проекта в netbeans7.4 Linux(Debian)

Tags: c++, linux, debian, netbeans

Установил netbeans, под OS Linux(Debian), но не могу запустить проект. Сразу уточню что ставил полную версию, хотя меня интересуют именно с++. Открыл пример проекта, который предоставлялся с установкой среды.

После запуска выбивает окошко настроек и просит вставить с++ компилятор.
[image]

Вставил как компилятор gcc(пробывал разное, ошибки те же). На этом же скрине внизу ошибки которые выдает среда.
[image]

Мб кто-то знает как решить эту проблему?

Все проблему решил.

Comment: `error trying to exec ccplus: no such file...` - у Вас компилятор не находится, нужно выставить в настройках нужный компилятор.

Comment: Проблему решили... А почему версия 7.4? Из репозитория устанавливали? Это зря. Скачайте с сайта поновее. И, как это не странно, будет стабильнее.